# приходит пустое тело в fetch request

Tags: javascript, c#, fetch

JavaScript:

```
    var url = "some url";

    var testDevice = {
        deviceFactory: 'IcpCon',
        deviceName: 'TestDeviceName',
        deviceDescription: 'TestDeviceDescription'
    };

    alert(JSON.stringify(testDevice)); //На этом алерте получаю корректную JSON строку

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(testDevice)
    })
    .then(response => {
        alert("Status: " + response.status); // здесь код 200
    })
```

Приложение, принимающее запросы:

```
    var context = await Listener.GetContextAsync();
    context.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    var request = context.Request;
    using(var response = context.Response)
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
    {
        var url = request.Url?.ToString();
        var body = new StringBuilder();
        body.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
        if(request.ContentType == "application/json")
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddDevice>(body.ToString()); //здесь тело уже пустое

            var newDevice = new List<DeviceItem>();

            var factory = FactoriesRepository.Factories.Where(x => x.Name == json.DeviceFactory).FirstOrDefault();
            var deviceMetaData = new DeviceMetadata(json.DeviceName, json.DeviceDescription);

            _devices.Add(new DeviceItem(factory.CreateDevice(DeviceIdGenerator.GenerateDeviceId(), deviceMetaData, factory.CreateDefaultConfiguration()))); //FIX DefaultConfiguration

            DevicesRepository.Devices = _devices.Select(x => x.Device).ToList().AsReadOnly();
        }
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Close();
    }
```

Ни одно решение, которое смог найти, не подошло

Comment: что за `Listener`? Что именно приходит в `context.Request`?

Comment: @Grundy похоже что `HttpListener` и `HttpListenerContext`.

Comment: @aepot, или что-то еще :)

Comment: @Grundy, да HttpListener